# HTML to Excel formatting: mso-number-format currency without decimal?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am exporting an asp.net grid to excel as html format file. Some of the cells in the asp.net grid are currency values without decimal digits. I can set the exported cell style  as

> mso-number-format: currency

to make a value of 12345 appear as $  12,345.00 in the excel file. 
But I'll like to remove the 2 decimal digits to make it  $  12,345

Does anyone know how to specify the cell style to make it appear as so?

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use custom formats for the cell.

for example for a comma separators with 2 decimal places use this:

`mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0\.00`

this is actually escaped value of: #,##0.00

**So:**

**» Use the following format to don't show trailing digits when they are zero:**

`mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0\.##`

its escaped value of: #,##0.##

**» And if you don't want decimal digits at all (even if they are not zero) you may use this:**

`mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0`

which is escaped value of: #,##0

Comment: Works well for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find useful patterns here:
    http://cosicimiento.blogspot.ru/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html